# Cordova Sqlite plugin is not adding the extension .db as it says in docs?

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

We are testing out the [Cordova Sqlite plugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) to see if it meets our needs for a particular app. So far our simple tests have worked just fine. However, we're stuck on this one bit. When creating the database, the documentation states:

> NOTE: The database file is created with `.db` extension.

In fact, in our tests, the database is created and later found and readable without any extension. The output matches our naming exactly. For instance, in this case:

```
var _dbName = 'testDB';
var _db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: _dbName});
```

The resulting file gets named exactly that, `testDB`, NOT `testDB.db` as the documentation suggests.

Our tests have been in iOS on the simulator. My concern is that this behavior is not reliable and will change on other platforms/hardware. I'm currently unable to test on Android.

*More context...*

The specific issue that I'm concerned with is that one platform might expect `.db` as documented, and another might not. The reason why it could be a problem is that we intend on using a prepopulated Sqlite database (moved by the app to the appropriate storage location prior to `openDatabase`). So the naming scheme of the packaged DB would make or break the situation.

**For future readers, please note... (Aug-4, 2014)**

A recent release of this plugin has rendered this question moot. As stated in their release notes, the `.db` extension is no longer added for Android, making the behavior of this plugin more consistent across platforms. From their release notes, as of the date of this edit:

> The automatic ".db" database file extension is now removed for the Android version, for consistency with the iOS & WP(8) versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in looking at the SQLitePlugin.m, the open: method has...

```
 NSMutableDictionary *options = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *dbname = [self getDBPath:[options objectForKey:@"name"]];
```

...which would indicate the database name is whatever you are passing to it. I did not see them append a 'db' extension anywhere in the plugin. I don't believe sqlite3_open() enhances the name, so I'm pretty sure the documentation you cited is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I think you got it. I took a look at the `getDBPath` method and this line: `NSString *dbPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", appDocsPath, dbFile];` corroborates your own observation. (I don't know why I didn't think to look at the source.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this plugin with **android**. Can't tell you if it's adding the .db or not. But I can assure you it's working just fine on android. Android also used exactly same way as you mentioned in your question.

```
var _dbName = 'testDB';
var _db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: _dbName});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So the specific issue that I'm concerned with is that one platform might expect the `.db` as documented, and another might not. The reason why it could be a problem is that we intend on using a prepopulated Sqlite database (moved by the app to the appropriate storage location prior to `openDatabase`). So the naming scheme of the packaged DB would make or break the situation.